# NPN condensor mic pre-amp really noisy

Tags: transistors, amplifier, noise, microphone, electret

I have designed a pre-amp and I am having a lot of noise when silent. It seems to be around 70 Hz on my scope, but jumps around.

I've tried adding bypass filters on the NPN emitter legs, as well as high-pass and low-pass filters on the signal line, without luck. I am not sure how to reduce this without firmware. The source is a clean 5 V supply straight off a battery, to eliminate any supply noise issues. I am really stumped!

Is there any way to reduce this? Decoupling caps on the main bus don't help either.

Thanks for the help! Please let me know if I am missing any information :)

[image: noise]

[image: schematic]

Comment: Is it [condenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Condenser) or [electret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Electret_condenser)? Big difference in terms of power supply. Electrets can work with 5 V, but condensers usually have a so-called "phantom-power" of 48 V (or so).

Comment: Hmm, my datasheet says Electret Condensor Microphone: https://www.cuidevices.com/product/resource/cma-4544pf-w.pdf

Comment: R4 is a huge noise source here, about 5 nV/sqrt(Hz) or 0.7 uV input referred, which would give about 70uV at the output since you only have about 40dB gain. So, if your Y axis is in mV you have other problems. How neat is the construction? Does the output sound white or is it just picking up hum?

Comment: If you are using an Arduino as an oscilloscope, then I wouldn't bet on those measurements being correct.  The data display from the Arduino IDE suggests you are using an Arduino as a scope.  The data rate (9600 baud) suggests you won't be getting anywhere near the sampling rate you think you are.

Comment: Not to mention that the Arduino power supply is not the cleanest thing.  If you are using the Arduino 5V for your amplifier, then you'll want to clean it up (low pass filter it.)